# How can I get the root word in Python?

Tags: python

I want to get the root of a word. I am not using a stemmer because I just want to do some replacements. Here is my code; it gives me correct results, except it does not replace the "ies" with "y" when a token ends in "ies":

```
import string;
contents = ["shoping", "balls", "babies"]
for token in contents:
    if token.endswith("ies"):
        string.replace(token,'ies','y',1)
        print token
    elif token.endswith('s'):
        print token[0:-1]
    elif token.endswith("ed"):
        print token[0:-2]
    elif token.endswith("ing"):
        print token[0:-3]
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit more to GoBusto's answer, the use of the string library is redundant (as well as the semi colon after import string).

You can  do this instead:

```
contents = ["shoping", "balls", "babies"]
for token in contents:
    if token.endswith("ies"):
        token = token.replace('ies','y',1)
        print token
    elif token.endswith('s'):
        print token[0:-1]
    elif token.endswith("ed"):
        print token[0:-2]
    elif token.endswith("ing"):
        print token[0:-3]
```

Answer (score 1):

`string.replace()` [returns a *new* string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace); it doesn't update the original one. You simply need to store the result before `print`ing it:

```
token = string.replace(token,'ies','y',1)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that even if you reassign `token`, that only effects that string while you're in the loop. The value in the list is not modified.

Answer (score 1):

`string.replace` didnt change the original `object`.It only returns replaced `string`.So store to another `variable` for further manipulations.Or if you want to print, then simply

```
if token.endswith("ies"):
    print string.replace(token, 'ies', 'y', 1)
```

But this solution didnt work if you want to replace `last` `ies` if there exists another `ies`.

**For example**

```
In [27]: token = "anyiesifies"

In [28]: string.replace(token, 'ies', 'y', 1)
Out[28]: 'anyyifies'
```